# Why is the W silent in "sword" but not in "swore"?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, phonology, silent-letter

The word "sword" is pronounced **/sɔːd/** (AmE: /sɔrd/) while "swore" is pronounced **/swɔː/** (AmE: /swɔr/). The W in "sword" is silent because of the following round vowel; the lips get round for **W** as well as the following round vowel so we round only once. I remember this explanation somewhere but I can't seem to find that answer now so I can't link it.

The word "swore" also has a round vowel after the W but the W is still pronounced and not silent like "sword". What's going on here? Why is it silent in "sword" but not in "swore"? Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32918/why-is-the-w-silent-in-sword

Comment: @djna I guess I saw it somewhere else. I don't think the explanation I'm talking about is present in this question. btw, I have read that answer and does not answer my question

Comment: "Swore" is the past tense of "swear", so it probably didn't have the same phonetic drift as other "swo-" words because it's grammatically tied to another "sw-" word with a different vowel.

Comment: Native english speaker here: I've never heard sword pronounced /sɔːd/, only /sɔɹd/... or however you spell that "or" sound in IPA. I forget.

Comment: @Hearth: /sɔːd/ is the pronunciation of 'sword' in non-rhotic accents.

Comment: *[Rhoticity in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English)*. *"The non-rhotic varieties include most of the dialects of modern England, Wales, Australia, New Zealand and South Africa."*

Comment: I always hear sword with a w....

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### TLDR

The **W** in 'two' and 'sword' is silent because of a sound change that took place somewhere between Old English & Middle English. The change applied to words in which the W was preceded by [s, t] and followed by a back vowel like [ɔ o ɑ u] etc.

'Swore' and 'sworn' also lost their W's at one point, but were later on restored by analogy with **swear**.

### The silent W in 'sword' and 'two'

Between Old English and Middle English, there was a sound change through which a /w/ was lost in the environment of a preceding [s] or [t] (and sometimes [h]) and a following [back vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_vowel) ([ɒ ɔ o ɑ u] etc). So 'two' was *twā* and its pronunciation was /twɑː/ in [Early Middle English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twa#Middle_English), it [became](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuo#Middle_English) /twoː/ and then it lost the /w/ and became /toː/ (the vowel /oː/ was shifted to /uː/ because of the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift#Overall_changes)).

'Sword' was [pronounced](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sword#Old_English) /sword/, it became /sord/ (or /sɔrd/). The conjunction/adverb 'so' [used to be pronounced with a /w/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swa#Old_English), but it lost its /w/ due to the same reason. The change also affected 'who' as it was *[hwa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hwa#Old_English)* before.

However, the change didn't occur when the /w/ was followed by a [front vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_vowel); for instance, 'twin' and 'swift' didn't lose their /w/'s because the w's in those words were followed by a front vowel /ɪ ~ i/.

Now 'swore' and 'swollen' deviate from this rule. They *do* have back vowels after the /w/ and there is an /s/ before the /w/, yet the /w/ is preserved. That's because of *Analogical change*.

### Analogical change

Before explaining 'swore', I'd like to elucidate 'analogy' (or [analogical change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogical_change)). It's ‘a type of language change in which some forms are deliberately changed merely to make them look more like other forms’ [[Trask](https://books.google.com/books?id=PHt-gNzagikC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22a+type+of+language+change+in+which+some+forms+are+deliberately+changed+merely+to+make+them+look+more+like+other+forms%22&source=bl&ots=x3iGh7vP8t&sig=ACfU3U1ePJTZjvr5PqGZnDoc8leuV5a6xg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyvtjJvoHyAhUMjhQKHTdoCxAQ6AEwAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22a%20type%20of%20language%20change%20in%20which%20some%20forms%20are%20deliberately%20changed%20merely%20to%20make%20them%20look%20more%20like%20other%20forms%22&f=false)].  Larry Trask, a phenomenal linguist, gives a remarkable insight into 'analogy' in his book [*Trask's Historical Linguistics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Trask_s_Historical_Linguistics.html?id=mQZSAQAAIAAJ). I'll just explain it the way Trask has explained with another example.

Suppose I tell you that *frumicate* is a rare and obscure English verb meaning *to put on airs*. I'm fairly certain you've never heard it before (because you haven't, have you?). What do you suppose its past tense is? You've never heard its past tense before, but I'm pretty sure you'll say *frumicated* (agree?). How do you know its past tense is *frumicated*?

‘You do it by invoking **analogy**’—that is, you assume that the required past tense is formed according to a very common pattern that is already familiar to you from large numbers of other English verbs. In this case, the pattern for forming past tense is so widespread and regular that it actually constitutes a *rule* of English grammar for regular verbs. <sup>[Adapted from Trask]</sup>

Trask gives another example:

- teach → taught
- catch → **?**

The past tense of 'catch' was formerly *[catched](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/269941/106592)*, but as a result of this analogy, it has become *caught* (which is now the standard past tense of 'catch').

### The /w/ in 'swore' and analogy with 'swear'

The same change (loss of /w/) should've happened with 'swore' and 'swollen', but these are nonetheless pronounced with a /w/ today.

It's possible though that the analogy of these forms—which always retained their /w/s because they had front vowels—prevented the regular sound change from affecting 'swore' and 'swollen'.

Or they *did* actually lose their /w/s at one point, but were later restored by the analogy with *swear* and *swell*. [see **Analogy and levelling** — [Trask's Historical Linguistics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Trask_s_Historical_Linguistics.html?id=mQZSAQAAIAAJ) pp101-102]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English#Until_Middle_English) says the same: /w/ in *swore* is due to analogy with *swear*. Another [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogical_change#Creation%2C_maintenance_and_restoration) article says that ‘[a]n example of analogical maintenance would be the perseverance of /w/ in *swollen* by analogy with the present tense *swell* (contrast with *sword*, where the /w/ is lost by regular sound change)’.

The change didn't apply to *swear* and *swell* because the /w/ in those words was followed by a front vowel and the sound change didn't affect words in which the /w/ was followed by front vowels.

Comment: I've definitely heard people pronounce the 'w' in "sword".  It's a dialect thing.  Not quite as obviously different as those who pronounce the first 'r' in "February" or the first 'd' in "Wednesday", but it hasn't completely died out.

Comment: @Ruslan: no. Void's answer says "They did lose their /w/s at one point, but were later restored by the analogy with swear and swell. "

Comment: Good answer! The process of creating irregular verbs by analogy is still ongoing of course. For instance, "snuck" instead of "sneaked", and (in North American dialects) "dove" instead of "dived", are both quite recent changes.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman  - Are you sure they weren't saying "sward" (an expanse of short grass)?

Comment: @Void - I wonder where the word "sward" fits in your explanation. Could it be that sward and sword became homophones at one point?  Maybe that would explain what happened.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: Good point! However, it [had a 'front' vowel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sweard#Old_English) /æ/ after the /w/ during the sound change.

Comment: @Muzer - Surely "sneak" should become "snoke" by analogy with "speak" and "spoke".

Comment: You talk about `south` vs `southern`, and `iron`... you don't even have to go that far! The numbers `one`, `two`, and `eight` are all spelled idiosyncratically.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Only if they meant "Draw your expanse of short grass!"  (It does seem to be mostly in period pieces, with people using more high-brow British accents, not sure how genuine it is, they might just be trying to sound pretentious...)

Comment: Teaching in public high schools I've often encountered the word "brung," the past tense of "bring."

Comment: @chasly Yes, _snuck_ is not really proper analogy, because there’s no proper parallel. It’s usually said to be from _stuck_ and _struck_, but obviously neither _stick_ nor _strike_ is close enough to _sneak_ to really invite analogy. It’s at best a very loose sort of generalised analogy (weak verb of the shape /sC(C)Vk/ gets /ʌ/ in the past tense). _Dove_ is more logical, having a very close parallel in _drive_ > _drove_.

Comment: Note that the pronunciations given here are from a regional dialect.

Comment: "English can be learnt through tough thorough thought, though" -- As non native speaker and a speaker from which the language is quite phonetic (dutch) that sentence trips me over multiple times. Even trying to understand that language is near impossible due to the sound being so weird. (I really had to speak it correctly myself before I understood it).

Comment: Just a note about your opening paragraph... this is well illustrated by the title of the published compendium of Theodore Geisel's pre-Dr. Seuss works: "The Tough Coughs As He Ploughs The Dough", which I've always believed was intended to be pronounced as "The Tuff Cuffs As He Pluffs The Duff".

Comment: @JasonS: [W's are destroying the numbers in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9kz2TaPBzs) -- just came across this and it reminded me of your comment above.