# Thrive-throve-thriven vs thrive-thrived-thrived

Tags: verbs, verb-usage, irregular-forms

> **thrived** vs **throve**

Could they be different in their usage?

There are two forms of inflection: ed-ed (regular) vs. irregular (like *drink-drank-drunk*)

When native speakers use the verbs as past which one is prevalent and is there any case that certain forms should be used?

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR

*Throve/thriven* and *thrived/thrived* are all correct; however, the regular forms are more prevalent than the irregular ones in Present Day English.

### Explanation

According to [this blog post](http://linguistics-research-digest.blogspot.com/2013/07/throve-and-dove-or-thrived-and-dived.html?m=1#:%7E:text=Although%20throve%20was%20the%20main,still%20uses%20throve%20at%20times.), *throve* was the original past tense of *thrive* used during the nineteeth century. That blog further says that it declined rapidly in use from 1910 onwards and seems to have regularised to *thrived*.

So what happened?

There was a plethora of regular verbs (whose past tenses end in *-ed*) and very few irregular verbs, people started associating *thrive* with regular verbs and regularised the original past tense *throve* (and *thriven*) to *thrived* by analogy with so many other regular verbs. The linked blog also says that Americans now only use *thrived* and *throve* can still be found in British English.

[**Analogy** (or 'analogical change')](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592)<sup>**1**</sup> is a type of language change in which some forms are deliberately changed merely to make them look more like other forms (Trask). (Go to the link where I've explained analogy in detail. I have explained why the W in 'sword' is silent but pronounced in 'swore'.)

According to James Blevins & Juliette Blevins ([*Analogy in Grammar* p1](https://books.google.com/books/about/Analogy_in_Grammar.html?id=5l0VDAAAQBAJ)), 'The human mind is an inveterate pattern-seeker. Once found, patterns are classified, related to other patterns, and used to predict yet further patterns and correlations'.

It means we tend to associate one form with another and make patterns as the examples in [this answer (analogy)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592) illustrate.

Analogical change can also perform in the opposite way, for instance, the original [past tense of *catch* was *catched*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/269941/106592), but was changed to the irregular *caught* by analogy with *taught*. And the irregular *drive-drove* is extended in some dialects of English to *dive*, so that *dive-dived* has become *dive-dove* (Trask).

Also see [Google Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=throve%2Cthriven%2Cthrived&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrove%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthriven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrived%3B%2Cc0):

> > [image: Google Ngram results for thrived, throve, thriven]

There's a decline in the use of *throve/thriven* and a sharp increase in the use of *thrived*.

Here are detailed graphs of the usage of 'throve' and 'thrived' in the 19th century:

> > [image: thrived Vs throve]
>
> [[*Language between description and prescription: Verbs and verb categories in nineteenth century grammars of English* by Lieselotte Anderwald](https://books.google.com/books/about/Language_Between_Description_and_Prescri.html?id=9NAdDAAAQBAJ) p90]

---

1. I cited [*Trask's Historical Linguistics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Trask_s_Historical_Linguistics.html?id=mQZSAQAAIAAJ) in another answer (to the question [Why is the W silent in “sword” but not in “swore”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/266263/106592)).

Comment: What is quite freaky is the way we apparently all started thriving in 1975

Comment: Great research and great answer.